# How to fix 403 error when i am trying laravel 5 project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5.1

I am trying to run the laravel 5 project using linux-mint and apache. My conf of virtual host /apache2/sites-available/mysite.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.local
ServerAlias www.mysite.local
DocumentRoot /home/kolya/workspace/mysite/public
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Rights issued a folder storage,
.htaccess is set defaulted laravel5,
I have error 403

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `/home/kolya/workspace/mysite/public` has set it's permissions to be readable by the user group where the apache engine belongs.

Comment: This folder /home/kolya/workspace/mysite/public has set 755 permissions, but i have error Forbidden 403 again.